# Current Month Without Using Selection - QlikView Set Analysis

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am stuck with some mysterious issue while trying to get Revenue for Current Month.
My Limitation is Simple :

***I need Current Month Revenue Without Having to do any selections.***

So here are the details :
**Data_Date** field has two values one for Dec, and one for Nov 2016

```
     11/15/2016
     12/15/2016
```

I have declared a variable **vCurrent_Month**

```
  =Date#( Max(Data_Date))
```

Value in Variable is correctly Reflecting **12/15/2016**

Given below is my Set Analysis Expression used in Text Object:

```
  =Sum({1<Date#(Data_Date)={"(vCurrent_Month)"}>}TOTAL_REVENUE)
```

I am getting following error

```
  Error: Error in set modifier expression
```

I have been stuck for hours and I have tried several tutorials and ways to get the same result but there seems to be no way out. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Sum({1<Data_Date={'$(vCurrent_Month)'}>}TOTAL_REVENUE)
```

Trying to do the number formatting in the first part of the set analysis is what is causing the error message you're getting.

After that to get it to work you need to make these changes:
You left out the $() expansion then the variable won't evaluate and you used double quotes which will return a field name rather than a value

Comment: thanks it worked.
Can you please elaborate as to why use used $(vCurrent_Month)
because as per my knowledge $ sign implies that we are referring to current selection. Where as my whole point  was that I did not want to select.
by the way your answer worked perfectly without any selection so thanks a lot.

Comment: Using the $ there is called dollar sign expansion and it refers to the variable not the Set Analysis. Dollar sign expansion tells QlikView to replace the variable with the text stored in the variable and then evaluate the resultant expression